# NServiceBus Message Handler Endless Loop

Tags: nservicebus

We have a system in production where one of the message processing services is hanging up.

Symptoms:

- Service using 100% CPU
- Restart of service doesn't resolve
- A message handler is called but never finished

We've looked at the code and it appears to be endless loop bug in the message handler.  Is there any way to configure NServiceBus to timeout handler processing and move the message to the error queue if the handler doesn't complete in a specified time?

Answer (score 1):

Was the message being processed on the infinite loop copied wholesale from the error queue?

I have seen this behavior before.

When you copy a message from the error queue back onto the input queue manually it does something weird with the message header which results in this hapenning.

Comment: I'm confirming that issue with the message headers, I think it was fixed but we corrected the ReturnToSourceQueue tool by using PowerShell instead.  I'd be happy to share the code if needed.

Comment: Here's the link to all the PS stuff: https://github.com/afyles/Blog/tree/master/PowerShell

Comment: No, the message was not copied from the error queue so it doesn't have anything with the headers